# How to repeat a button in DataView

Tags: wicket

I can't get the button to appear on the page. Both of the labels appear fine just wondering how to get the button to show up too.

```
   ListDataProvider listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider(users);

    DataView dataView = new DataView<UserDetails>("row", listDataProvider) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(Item<UserDetails> item) {
            UserDetails user = item.getModelObject();

            RepeatingView repeatingView = new RepeatingView("dataRow");
            repeatingView.add(new Label(repeatingView.newChildId(), user
                    .getUserName()));
            repeatingView.add(new Label(repeatingView.newChildId(), user
                    .getAddress()));
            repeatingView.add(new Button(repeatingView.newChildId()));

            item.add(repeatingView);

        }

    };

    dataView.setItemsPerPage(5);
    add(dataView);
    add(new PagingNavigator("pagingNavigator", dataView));
```

And my html is this:

```
    <table>
     <tr>
     <th>Name</th><th>Address</th>
     </tr>

     <tr wicket:id = "row">
        <td wicket:id="dataRow"></td>
     </tr>
     </table>

     <div wicket:id="pagingNavigator"></div>
```

Comment: A Button needs specific markup. You'll have to add a Panel or a fragment containing the Button, not just the Button.

Comment: May be a simple way is use a button and attach it with the form(do accordingly with markup).